# Gson:Is there a way to parse only specific internal JSON lists using GSON?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a json which looks like this

```
{response:{"status":{"....."},data:[{"name":"Alice","id":"123"},{"name":"Jack","id":"345"},......]}
```

The classes to parse this looks like below:-

```
public class TheData{
   public List<Users> data;
}

public class Users{
     public String name;
     public String id;
}
```

And then:-

```
TheData theData=gson.fromJson(jsonresponse,TheData.class)
```

Well all this simple but the json is wrapped in a "response" tag. I can create another class for the same  and get this parsed but is there any other way I can handle this with GSON.

Comment: So you only want to pull out the 'data' portion from the json?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For some reason that I do not know right now, a `Gson` object parses your JSON string as a primitive.

Instead use a `JsonParser` to get a `JsonElement` as a `JsonObject` from which you can retrieve the inner `"response"` `JsonObject`.

```
// after some cleanup of the string
String str = "{\"response\":{\"status\":{\"id\":45},\"data\":[{\"name\":\"Alice\",\"id\":123},{\"name\":\"Jack\",\"id\":345}]}}";

JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject element = (JsonObject)parser.parse(str);

JsonElement responseWrapper = element.get("response");

Gson gson = new Gson();
TheData data = gson.fromJson(responseWrapper, TheData.class);
System.out.println(data);
```

With some `toString()` added, prints

```
[[name = Alice, id = 123], [name = Jack, id = 345]]
```

The `Gson` object can parse the inner `JsonElement` as a `TheData` object, ignoring the `status` field.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively of using Gson lib for this, you can just use the built in Java JSONObject in order to get the inner json object. And then you can do whatever you need with the String of the inner Json (you can then parse it with Gson or any other parser lib)

```
       String jsonStr = "{\"response\":{\"status\":{\"id\":45},\"data\":[{\"name\":\"Alice\",\"id\":123},{\"name\":\"Jack\",\"id\":345}]}}";

        JSONObject jsonObj = null;
        try{
              jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr).getJSONObject("response");
        }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

       if(jsonObj != null) jsonStr = String.valueOf(jsonObj);
```