# Gson get list of objects from json

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization, android-json

I have a json string that contains a array of objects(filters array). The json string has other objects and fields too but im interested in only parsing the json array. Can anyone tell me how can I do this using Gson?

Here is my json file:

```
{
  name: "test json", 
  test_ob: {
    name: "test"
  } 

  filters[
    {
    test: 1,
    test: 2,
    ...
    }
    ...


  ]
}
```

and my code:

```
 Filters filters = new Gson().fromJson(JSONcontent.toString(), Filters.class);
```

And my filters class:

```
public class Filters {

    private List<Filter> filters;

    public List<Filter> getFilters() {
        return filters;
    }

    public void setFilters(List<Filter> filters) {
        this.filters = filters;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204465/gsonis-there-a-way-to-parse-only-specific-internal-json-lists-using-gson

Answer (score 0):

Is your json valid? Try this:

data.json:

```
{
  name: "test json", 
  test_ob: {
    name: "test"
  },
  filters: [
    {
        name: filter1,
        value: 1
    },
    {
        name: filter2,
        value: 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Filter.java:

```
public class Filter {
    private String name;
    private String value;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Data.java:

```
public class Data {
    private List<Filter> filters;

    public List<Filter> getFilters() {
        return filters;
    }

    public void setFilters(List<Filter> filters) {
        this.filters = filters;
    }
}
```

Test.java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        Object obj;
        try {
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\data.json"));
            JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) obj;

            Data data = gson.fromJson(jsonObject, Data.class);

        } catch (JsonIOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I'll try this and get back to you